# How to rotate points given in square grid?

Tags: transformation, rotations

[image]

I really hope you can see this picture.
So My question is 
1) If the figure is rotated 90 degrees counter clock wise about Point O, then:
$$a. G to _________$$ 
$$b. _________ to P $$
How would i rotate i don't even know how to start this?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a line from $O$ to $G$ and $O$ to $P$. What points form a line with $O$ that is $90$ degrees to these lines?

Taking the direction of the rotation into account, then you would get
$$G \text{ to } E$$
and
$$N \text{ to } P$$

Comment: So the basic idea for this is the i imagine an line from the point it wants rotate? Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: This exercise is just to help your visualization, so yes that is all you have to do. If you can visualize the transformation in another way, that's fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Get out a piece of trace paper (or such) and trace the image you have shown us. Rotate it $90^\circ$ and see what you get.

As far as coordinates go, a rotation of $90^\circ$ tranforms the point with coordiates $(x,y)$ to a point with coordinates $(-y, x)$. Using $\overleftrightarrow{OF}$ as the $x$-axis and $\overleftrightarrow{ON}$ as the $y$-axis, $G(1,-1)$ becomes the point $E(1,1)$. Let $W(x,y)$ be the point that gets sent to $P(-1,0)$. Then we must have $(-y,x) = (-1,0)$ So $(x,y)=N(0,1)$.